# Python firebase_admin hangs when connecting to firestore emulator

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am unable to connect to firestore emulator from python. Connecting and writing documents to a real project works fine, but when setting the env. variable "FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST" the set-function never resolves. The code:

```
os.environ["FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST"]="localhost:8081"
os.environ["GCLOUD_PROJECT"]="my_project"
cred = credentials.Certificate('./firebase_cert.json')

default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()

doc_ref = db.collection(u'test').document()
doc_ref.set({
    u'hello': "test"
})

print("Document stored successfully.")
```

My firebase.json:

```
{
    "emulators": {
        "firestore": {
           "port": 8081
          },
         "ui": {
         "enabled": true
     } }
  }
```

What could cause this?

UPDATE:
I tried different things to figure out if this is a port issue and got the following in firebase-debug.log.

1. Set port to 8080 in firebase.json:

   Jul 08, 2021 12:42:50 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.NotFoundHandler handleRequest
   INFO: Unknown request URI: /app/agents/protocols
2. Set port to 8081 in firebase.json:

   Jul 08, 2021 12:42:00 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
   INFO: Detected non-HTTP/2 connection.
3. Not set port at all in firebase.json (force default port)

   Jul 08, 2021 12:46:06 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.NotFoundHandler handleRequest
   INFO: Unknown request URI: /app/agents/protocols

I dug into the google cloud package and found that the code at least executes until this point (line 821 in venv/Lib/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/services/firestore/client.py):

```
response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
```

Comment: I ran your code and it worked for me. My guess is that maybe the emulator you are running is not on port 8081? If the port doesn't match, the Python script does indeed stall. Given that the default port on the emulator is 8080, maybe your emulator didn't pick up the changed port from the json file?

Comment: Tried different port settings to figure out if this was the issue, still same problem. See updated question.

Comment: I am out of ideas. My last suggestion is delete everything and start all over again. Maybe there was something not configured correctly in your previous set up.

Comment: Same here. Thanks for the time man.

Answer (score 1):

Downgraded the `firebase-admin` SDK from `5.0.2` to `4.5.1` and the downgrade fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by using the LAN's IP address for my machine instead of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. This has worked for me in the past for other inconsistent behavior with the emulator as well. Everything else as far as config goes is identical to the code sample provided in the question. The JSON file I used for the credential was from my real Firebase project.