# What credentials to use to connect to firebase emulator using firebase_admin in python?

Tags: python, firebase-admin, firebase-tools

We are trying to connect to the firebase emulator (storage specifically) using python. Here is our code:

```
from firebase_admin import credentials, initialize_app
initialize_app(credential=None, options={'storageBucket': app.config['STORAGE_BUCKET']})
```

This returns an error `google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application.`

We also tried mocking the credential:

```
from firebase_admin import credentials, initialize_app
credentials = mock.Mock(spec=google.auth.credentials.Credentials)
initialize_app(credential=credentials, options={'storageBucket': app.config['STORAGE_BUCKET']})
```

But this just throws the error: `ValueError: Illegal Firebase credential provided. App must be initialized with a valid credential instance.`

Does anyone know how to get the firebase_admin sdk to connect to the emulators?

Answer (score 0):

This post might be helpful, I was able to connect to my emulator using the sample (with some modifications): [Python firebase_admin hangs when connecting to firestore emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68272114/python-firebase-admin-hangs-when-connecting-to-firestore-emulator/70989739#70989739)